# Webpack and moment.js don't work together

Tags: webpack, momentjs

`moment.js` needs to load globally because many third party libraries assume it is there. Webpack seems to only work by bundling the code into a module and making it **un**available globally. e.g.

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

I can't make changes to third party libraries (such as AngularJS), so it seems Webpack is completely incompatible with `moment.js`. It this right? Is the only way to get `moment.js` to work by bypassing Webpack? Is there some way to get Webpack to load a library such as `moment.js` globally?